# Schrodinger equation with magnetic vector potential

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

In many papers dealing with the Schrodinger equation with magnetic potential
$$u_t=i(\nabla+iA(t,x))^2u$$
the authors say that this equation can be studied with Kato's methods for abstract evolution equations. Is there someone who can suggest some reference in which this approach is used?

Comment: I guess you mean $u_t = i(\nabla+iA)^2 u$ (otherwise the equation is not self-adjoint).

Comment: Do you mean operator splitting?

Comment: No I mean methods for the study of abstract evolution equation (like stable families of generator of continuous semigroups)

Comment: What exactly are you interested in? The operator on the RHS is skew-adjoint (provided you have "good" boundary conditions and/or reasonable magnetic potential), hence it generates a unitary group on $L^2$ by Stone's Theorem. What is usually referred to as "Kato's theory" is a collection of much deeper results on admissible scalar potentials.

Comment: Quite frequently (though I cannot guarantee it) in this context the reference to "Kato's methods" refers to the developments centered around his two papers http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=279626 and http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=326483 The theory is strong enough that oftentimes authors just refers to it as a blackbox guaranteeing the existence of "evolution" for the linear operator. But you can probably find something interesting if you look at MathSciNet references to those two papers.

Comment: You can apply Stone's theorem if the vector potential doesn't depend on time. In the time-dependent case you have to proceed in different ways.

Comment: I think the two papers mentioned by Willie Wong are a good hint. For instance Theorem 1 of the second Kato paper is applied in Corollary 8 of the paper "Existence of a Unique Local Solution to the Many-body Maxwell-Schrödinger Initial Value Problem", see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3680).

Comment: @gsa thanks. I'll see the paper you linked

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following references will be helpful:
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01682741 (Remarks on schrödinger operators with vector potentials, by Tosio Kato),
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077313102 (Schrödinger operators with magnetic fields. I. general interactions, by J. Avron, I. Herbst, and B. Simon).

Many relevant references can be found through these two more recent articles:
http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0510055 (Recent developments in quantum mechanics with magnetic fields, by Laszlo Erdos) and http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.8210 (Magnetic Schrödinger operators and Manes critical value, by Peter Herbrich).